# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Wifi device not ready- Acer Predator Laptop

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros

I'm using an Acer Predator Helios 300 and have recently dual booted Ubuntu 16.04.

I cannot connect to Wi-fi as it shows:

```
Wifi device not ready.
```

[image]

I have run the network diagnostic test as recommended and here is the link to the file obtained: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3z9HwFC2th/

I believe that one of my firmware files is missing because the diagnostic file shows the following:

```
[    8.312533] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    8.316678] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    8.316683] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    8.385085] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2
```

I also did take a look at online at https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0 to fetch the missing firmware files but Git repo does not contain `firmware-5.bin`.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci-nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have executed those commands and attached a snapshot of the result.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added network diagnostics link. Thanks for guiding me through so far.

Comment: Looks like the firmware data is missing. Did you install the `linux-firmware` package? If not, please do (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`) and reboot. If the installation fails please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of the installation command(s). Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I did run that command and the result stated that - 0 new upgrades. But surprisingly the issue had been resolved and Wi-fi is working. Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the installation of the `linux-firmware` package (with a temporary internet connection) solved the issue:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-firmware
```